# iOS13 Dark Mode Disclosure Indicator: Not readable

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-darkmode

I have custom UITableView where I set the background color to white. This works for dark and bright mode. But on dark mode the disclosure indicators are hard to see.

I tried to fix this with cell.tint color but it doe not work. How can I fix it?

Dark Mode:

[image]

Bright Mode:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the table view to always be light, regardless of the system setting, you should consider to set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light` in your table view or view controller to force the system to always use light style colors.

Comment: This addresses the visibility of the disclosure indicator by forcing the view to use light colours.  The problem is that the table view will show in light mode when all else is dark?

Comment: @JonTrauntvein Correct. But OP said they set the background color to white, so I assumed that it should be light in both cases.

Comment: Schiegel I'm having a similar problem but am trying to make the app dark-mode conformant.  The problem that I am. seeing now is that, when I put a disclosure indicator on a cell, the component renders this as a more or less white square with no visible chevron but it looks fine in light mode.  I can only assume that this is a bug in the component or the OS and the only workaround that I have seen so far is your suggestion to disable dark mode for the view.

Comment: This answer is possible only in iOS 13 and later